# Control deployed applications on JBoss 7 from a deployed application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

i try to control (start, stop, redeploy and so on) applications on a JBoss server in a programmatic way for testing purposes.

I already found the  [DeploymentManager](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/7.1.2.Final/javax/enterprise/deploy/spi/DeploymentManager.html) which seems to provide the needed features. But i need some documentation on how to setup the jboss server and find the URI for the DeploymentFactoryManager.

Any pointers for how to find this documentation or a simpler way to controll deployed applications without manual intervention?

Regards,
eqinox76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what exactly do you need, you could use [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) together with JBoss AS container to operate on deployments and applications during runtime of your tests.

In case your scenario is different you can use [JBoss CLI](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-The_Management_CLI.html) so you can control your server via command line interface (and you will also will get the ability to write scripts for your use case).

Comment: Thanks i now used the cli way and will have a look into Arquillian.
I was hoping for a more java only way without the need to execute a commandline.